How to cleanly stop a robot in the destructor of the code
I often use CTRL-C to stop my ROS2 code.
However, I wonder why my destructor is not executed or not executed in sequence.
According to my log file, the destructor was called:
[INFO] [1712382503.696874002] [ROS2_Std_LaserScan]: MOVE FASTER
^C[INFO] [1712382503.748620042] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[INFO] [1712382503.748933363] [ROS2_Std_LaserScan]: Shutdown LaserScanner

But the robot keeps spinning.
My sample code:
class LaserScanner : public rclcpp::Node
{
    public: LaserScanner(): Node ("ROS2_Std_LaserScan")
    {
        auto default_qos = rclcpp::QoS(rclcpp::SystemDefaultsQoS());

        scanner = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>("scan", default_qos, std::bind(&LaserScanner::callback_ls, this, std::placeholders::_1));
        runner = this->create_publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>("cmd_vel", default_qos);
    }
    
    ~LaserScanner()
    {
        stop = 1;
        run.linear.x = 0.0;
        run.angular.z = 0.0;
        runner->publish(run);
        sleep(0.1);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Shutdown LaserScanner");
    }

    private:
    void callback_ls(const sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr msg)
    {
        scan = msg;
        decode_scan();
    }

    void decode_scan()
    {
        float sum_dist = 0.0;
        int count = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < scan->ranges.size(); i++)
        {
            float rad = scan->angle_min + i * scan->angle_increment;
            float grad = rad / M_PI * 180; 
            //if (scan->ranges[i] >= scan->range_min || scan->ranges[i] <= scan->range_max)
            if ((grad < -175.0) || (grad > 175.0))
            { 
                sum_dist = sum_dist + scan->ranges[i];
                count++;
            }
        }    
        this->move(sum_dist / count);
    }

    void move(float x)
    {
        if (stop == 1)
            x = 0.0;
        //geometry_msgs::msg::Twist run;
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Estimated distance: %f", x);

        if (x <= 0.3)
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "STOP");
            run.linear.x = 0.0;
            run.angular.z = 0.0;
            runner->publish(run);
        } 
        else if (x <= 0.6)
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "TURN");
            run.linear.x = 0.1;
            // turn left:    
            run.angular.z = 0.5;
            // turn right
            //run.angular.z = -x
            runner->publish(run);
            //sleep(0.5);
        } 
        else if (x <= 1.0)
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "MOVE");
            run.linear.x = 0.1;
            run.angular.z = 0.5;
            runner->publish(run);
            //sleep(0.5);
        } 
        else 
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "MOVE FASTER");
            run.linear.x = 0.1;
            run.angular.z = 0.5;
            runner->publish(run);
            //sleep(0.5);
        }
        sleep(0.1);
    }

    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>::SharedPtr scanner;
    rclcpp::Publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>::SharedPtr runner;

    sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr scan;
    geometry_msgs::msg::Twist run;

    int stop = 0;

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<LaserScanner>());
    rclcpp::shutdown();

    return 0;
}

